# How can i get axios to maintian cookie for web scraper

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios

I'm looking to make a NodeJS **scraper** that will automatically log in and POST some data but I'm struggling with getting the session to persist with the axios library (since request is now deprecated). I looking for user to get logged in and keep user logged in and whenever the script is run i don't want to signin again also let me fetch other api request without passing cookie everytime, Here is my code.

index.js

```
async function main() {
    const account = {
        email: prompt('Enter Truepush Email: '),
        password: prompt('Enter Password: '),
    }
    console.log(`Processing account ${account.email}----------`);
    await downloadStatsForAccount(account);
}

async function downloadStatsForAccount(account) {
    if (!account.email || !account.password) throw new Error("Input cannot be empty");

    let client = new ScrapeTruepush();
    let loginResult = await client.getLoginResult(account);

    console.log(loginResult)
}
```

apicalls:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default;
const tough = require('tough-cookie');

axiosCookieJarSupport(axios);

class ScrapeTruepush {
    _api;
    constructor() {
        this._api = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://app.truepush.com/',
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        axiosCookieJarSupport(this._api);
        this._api.defaults.jar = new tough.CookieJar();
    }

    async getLoginResult(account) {
        if (!account) throw new Error("No account found");
        return await this._api.post('api/v1/login', account).then((r) => r)
    }
}
```

I want to login and save my cookies to avoid login again. error when trying to login:

```
data: {
    status_code: 'XSRF-ERROR',
    status: 'ERROR',
    message: 'Cross domain requests are not accepting to this endpoint. If you cleared the cookies, please refresh your browser.'
  }
```

Comment: FYI 'scrapper' (and 'scrap') means throwing away like rubbish. The correct term is __scraper__ (and __scrape__)